# Python Pandas column type conversion succeeds in changing type but changes inherent value

Tags: python, pandas, types

I am reading a .tsv in pandas with the following commands:

```
Gene_Data = pd.read_csv(
        genes_input_path,
        sep='\t+',
        header=None,
        engine='python',
        names=col_names,
        usecols=col_to_use,
        comment='#')

   
Gene_Data.Stop = Gene_Data.Stop.astype('float32')
```

Where the input data looks something like:

```
    chr7    HAVANA  gene    117287120       117715971       .       +       .       ID=ENSG00000001626.16;gene_id=ENSG00000001626.16;gene_type=protein_coding;gene_name=CFTR;level=1;hgnc_id=HGN
```

And the Stop column corresponds to the 4th column when using 0 indexing.
When I perform the astype conversion to float32 it ends up changing that Stop column value to 1177159**68**. Rather than returning the actual value of 117715971.

When I disable the type conversion, it keeps the value as int64, and the value is correct. I don't understand why it is changing the inherent value when performing the conversion, does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: Because float32 doesn't have enough precision to store that number exactly. Who not `float64` or `int64`?

Comment: I didn't think I was running up against the limit for float32 usage. Is that what is happening here?

Comment: @DjNeckbrace It's not about the _limit_ of float32, it's about the precision, or loss of precision in this case. Read [more about that here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/1431750).